# What is the clean way to check a SELECT query result's length in MVVM architecture?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata

I am creating an App that will use a SearchView to let user make queries to filter data. I am using RoomDB, and trying to follow Model-View-ViewModel architecture as recommended in [Android Developers' Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide?hl=es-419).

I have one entity and one DAO (for now my DB has only one table). I have a method in the DAO that looks like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = :search OR column2 = :search")
LiveData<List<TableRow>> filteredSearch(String search);
```

So, from an AsyncTask I can use the RoomDatabase's instance, right, and obtain the results of an user's query, **like this**, right?

```
// Let's assume search already contains user's input
String search;

// DatabaseClient is a singleton that holds MyRoomDatabase instance
// I am using it as Repository for now... bad call?
LiveData<List<TableRow>> user_query = DatabaseClient
                     .getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                     //  my DatabaseClient has this method that
                     // I made to call DAO's query method
                     .getFilteredList(search);
```

So, I want to load one fragment or another in my Main Activity depending on this user query's length (if 0 results, fragmentA else fragmentB). This is business logic to some extent? I wonder... should I read the query's length from the Viemodel, or from the View (AKA Activity)? As you can see, I am still struggling with RoomDB and ViewModels at all.

My plan was making a method in the ViewModel that returns the `LiveData<List<TableRow>>` with the query results by using a code snippet similar to the one above, and then, from the MainActivity:

```
search_view.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        //  Should I delegate AsyncTask to the Repository AKA
        // DatabaseClient? Maybe... but please bear with me
        class UserSearchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<TableRows>> {
            @Override
            protected List<TableRows> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                TableRowsViewModel my_viewmodel = new TableRowsViewModel(getApplication());
                LiveData<List<TableRows>> search_results;
                search_results = my_viewmodel.getUserSearch(query);
                // TODO I will care about type mismatches later
                return search_results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<TableRows> found_elements) {
                super.onPostExecute(found_elements);
                // TODO So, I want to check user's search results from here
                if ( found_elements.length > 0) {
                    showFragmentB();
                } else {
                    showFragmentA();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have been without coding for more than half year, and I am a little rusty. I forgot concepts that I knew before about ViewModels, LiveData and stuff. Am I breaking MVVM's architecture with my approach? What's the role of LiveData in this kind of logic attempt of mine? Can I read the SQL query result's length directly from some LiveData's method, or else, I should retrieve the list from it to do so?

**I guess the actual question is:** is my approach wrong? What would be the cleanest way to implement my fragment's logic depending on user search's length?

EDIT: I am not asking only about good practices (which are still welcome); I have barely dedicated 7 hours to this app yet and I couldn't still build a first alpha version to start testing it. My first priority in short-term is putting this thing together (and myself together I might add); in other words: *first, I want to make it work even if it is not clean*. Right now I am a simple-minded monkey which just thinks about this like if this was a normal PC app in which I don't have to struggle with App lifecycles, multithreading and all related stuff,in which I just retrieve the SQL query's result right away. I beg your pardon for my ignorance.

So, in order to add more context about what I am trying to do: If searxh results are zero, fragmentA would be a form for adding a new row to the table; fragmentB would show just the data of the first row, not listing yet (I will reach there eventually, but not yet).

Comment: if you are using livedata, you should avoid using AsyncTask. `AsyncTask` is deprecated

Comment: @Teo Good point, but I can't make SQL queries from the main thread using RoomDb, right? I am still figuring out where to summon another thread for this.

Comment: U are using livedata, you should create an observer for this livedata to get its value.

Comment: @Teo Perhaps I need an observer, but is that so? Even if I just want the LiveData list to get updated only on user's query? I don't even know if I should use LiveData in these cases at all... can a ViewModel work without LiveData? I don't even know... :-(

Comment: I mean, I remembered LiveData<> deals with Android app's Lifecycle and stuff... but I don't remember the details... I'm ashamed of myself right now

Comment: I'd love to keep feeding you back about my question's details, guys, but for now I gotta sleep, because tomorrow I gotta go to work (which is not, in any way, computer-related). In fact, I should be sleeping already instead of messing up with code right now xD, I have 7 hours or less to sleep). I will keep an eye to this question from my work using my smartphone, but I won't be able to use my computer until I get out of work. Sorry about that ^^'

Comment: I could invest 2 hours more on this today, and I am starting to think I am close to be able to make the first alpha build. I made a new Repository class to handle the DatabaseClient (the singleton of RoomDatabase), and I am handling the AsyncTasks from the Repository. And it looks like needing an Observer was inevitable at all (good point @Teo). I might update the question accordingly eventually (there's still the issue that AsyncTasks are deprecated). BTW it seems that for "read methods" I can just do them in the main thread? Or rather I shouldn't?

Comment: LiveData from Room handles threading internally. There is zero reason for you to use AsyncTask in this scenario.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce maybe... for Read operations perhaps... but this is not the same for Create, Update and Delete operations, is it?

Comment: Now I have gone beyond the problem of reading the amount of results of a SELECT statement (this part I already solved it, using LiveData and an Observer). Now I am stuck with another issue: creating a row and it's children in another table (binded by FOREIGN KEY). So, maybe I should self-answer this question (even though I am not sure my way is the most clean at all) and start a new one...

Comment: ...and so I did: I auto-answered this question and started a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69446377/3692177) to separate the different concerns in different questions, as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I ended up implementing the logic I had in mind when I made the question. But that doesn't mean this is the clean way to do it.

In order to get the size of the User query, I ended up using an Observer (as Teo said in his comment). I am not sure if using Observer and LiveData for a Database that is merely local in the phone's app (and therefore shall only be modified by the App's user himself) for obtaining query results each time the user hits "Search" button, I am not sure if using Oberser and LiveData for this is overkill or not... and the aberration of using DatabaseClient (the RoomDatabase's singleton) as a Repository? Not anymore... I have created a dedicated Repository Class to handle the DatabaseClient and the DAOs.

That said, the relevant part of my Repository class:

```
public class Repository {
    private final TableRowDao tablerow_dao;

    public Repository(Application application) {
        AppDatabase app_db = DatabaseClient.getInstance(application).getAppDatabase();
        tablerow_dao = app_db.tableRowDao();
    }

    public LiveData<List<TableRow>> getFilteredList(String search) {
        return tablerow_dao.filteredSearch(search);
    }
    // [...]
```

...here, the ViewModel:

```
public class TableRowsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private Repository repository;

public TableRowsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    repository = new Repository(application);
}

public LiveData<List<TableRow>> getUserSearch(String search) {
    return repository.getFilteredList(search);
}
```

**No AsyncTasks were used for this purpose.**

In MainActivity, within OnCreate method:

```
search_view.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        my_viewmodel = new TableRowsViewModel(getApplication());
        search_results = my_viewmodel.getUserSearch(query);

        observeSearchResults(search_results);
        return true;
    }

    // [...]
});
```

ObserveSearchResults is a private method that I declared in MainActivity as well:

```
// Having a observer is good and stuff, but am I overdoing it?
private void observeSearchResults(LiveData<List<TableRow>> search_results) {
    search_results.observe(this, new Observer<List<TableRow>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<TableRow> rows) {
            if ( rows.size() > 0 ) {
                // TODO I don't list the results yet, I show the first one right away
                profileFragment = ProfileFragment.newInstance(rows.get(0));
                transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, profileFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            } else {
                transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, insertFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This worked for me, **but that doesn't mean that I am doing this in a clean way at all**.