# How can I create row and children related by ForeignKey with RoomDB in a clean way?

Tags: java, android, relational-database, android-room, auto-increment

This question is somehow related to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69384937/3692177), because it is the same project but now I am trying to go one more step forward.

So, in my previous question I only had one table; this time I have two tables: the new second table is supposed to contain related attributes for the rows of the first table, in a OneToMany relationship. So, I store a ForeignKey in the second table that would store the Row ID of the first table's related row (obviously).

**The problem is this:** the intention is creating both registers (parent and child) at the same time, using the same form, and ParentTable uses AUTO_INCREMENT for his PrimaryKey (AKA ID).

Due to how RoomDb works, I do the creation using a POJO: but after insertion, this POJO won't give me the auto-generated ID as far as I know... so, the only workaround I am able to imagine is, when submitting the form, first make the INSERT for the parent, then using one of the form's fields that created the parent to make some kind of "SELECT * FROM parent_table WHERE field1 LIKE :field1", retrieving the ID, and then use that ID to create the child table's POJO and perform the next INSERT operation. However I feel something's not right about this approach, the last time I implemented something similar this way I ended up with a lot of Custom Listeners and a callback hell (I still have nightmares about that).

About the Custom Listeners thing, it is the solution I ended up choosing for a different problem for a different project (more details about it in this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52442384/how-can-i-make-some-class-running-in-the-main-thread-await-concurrently-for-ot/52493936#52493936)). Taking a look to that old question might help adding some context about how misguided I am in MVVM's architecture. However, please notice the current question has nothing to do with WebServices, because the Database is purely local in the phone's app, no external sources.

However, I am wondering: isn't this overkill (I mean the `INSERT parent -> SELECT parentID -> INSERT child` thing)? Is it inevitable having to do it this way, or there is rather a more clean way to do so?

---

The "create method" in my Repository class looks like this:

```
public void insertParent(Parent parent) {
    new InsertParentAsyncTask(parent_dao).execute(parent);
}

private static class InsertParentAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Parent, Void, Void> {
    private final ParentDao parent_dao;
    private InsertParentAsyncTask(ParentDao parent_dao) {
        this.parent_dao = parent_dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Parent... parents) {
        parent_dao.insert(parents[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Trying to follow Mario's answer, I changed this method in my parent's DAO:

```
// OLD
@Insert
void insert(Parent parent);

// NEW (yes, I use short type for parent's ID)
@Insert
short insert(Parent parent);
```

**EDIT2:**
Now, I am trying to make changes to my Repository's insert AsyncTask, like this:

```
private static class InsertParentAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Parent, Void, Short> {
    private final ParentDao parent_dao;
    private InsertParentAsyncTask(ParentDao parent_dao) {
        this.parent_dao = parent_dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Short doInBackground(Parent... parents) {
        short parent_id;
        parent_id = parent_dao.insert(parents[0]);
        return parent_id;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Short hanzi_id) {
        // TODO ??? What now?
    }
}
```

### LONG STORY SHORT

It worked for me this way down here, but this ain't clean code (obviously):

```
// TODO I am aware that AsyncTask is deprecated
// My Repository class uses this
public void insertParentAndChildren(Parent parent, String[] children_list) {
    new InsertParentAndChildrenAsyncTask(parent_dao, children_list).execute(parent);
}

private static class InsertParentAndChildrenAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Parent, Void, Short> {
    private final ParentDao parent_dao;
    private String[] children_list;
    private InsertParentAndChildrenAsyncTask(ParentDao parent_dao, String[] children_list) {
        this.parent_dao = parent_dao;
        this.children_list = children_list;
    }

    @Override
    protected Short doInBackground(Parent... parents) {
        short parent_id;
        Long row_id = parent_dao.insert(parents[0]);
        parent_id = parent_dao.getIdForRowId(row_id);
        return parent_id;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Short parent_id) {
        // Second "create method" for children
        for (int n = 0; n < children_list.length; n++) {
            Child child = new Child();
            child.setParentId( parent_id );
            child.setMeaning( children_list[n] );
            // My Repository has this method as well
            insertChildStaticMethod(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try `SELECT last_insert_rowid()` as a query on room (you write it just like that no need to reference any table). This statement returns the rowid of the last insertion into your database. By default rowId is what most sql DBs use as primary keys when you define them as auto incremental integers. so I guess you would define the following method in your DAO

```
@Query("SELECT last_insert_rowid()")
public abstract int getLastId()

@Insert
void insert(Parent parent)
```

then you can use it together with your insert statement in a transaction. like so

```
@Transaction
public int insertAndGetPrimaryKey(Parent parent){
    insert(parent);
    return getLastId();
}
```

it is important to use transaction as else the id delivered could be the wrong one if in your app multiple threads could potentially modify the tables at the same time.

btw I would not use short for a primary key. not only is it short XD (only 32k capacity) but the satndard is really to use Integer (4 bn capacity). if these were the 80's id be all for it (those are 2 entire bytes that you are saving after all XD)  but now a days memory is cheap and abundant and as i said integer is what DBs work with by default.

Comment: Impressive! Clean solution for both monothreading and multithreading Android's Java code! Using DB default's primary key is a good point about Clean Code issues as well.

Comment: happy to help!!

Comment: did this end up working for you? there is an alternatinve where you sort the parent table by rowId in desc order and limit to the first row. but it should be exactly the same code functionally and you would still want to use the transaction. the only difference is that it would allow you to use any other type as a primary key (which in my oppinion isnt really that usefull)

Comment: ...I'd like to give you feedback about this, but unfortunately I didn't have time to refactor yet. I barely can dedicate one or two hours per day to code (the days I feel like coding, because I work 9,5 hours each day 6 days per week (this week 7 days T_T)... For now, my coding hours go for anything but refactoring... T_T

Comment: However, I know about Database transactions and what they are for; so, even without having your code tested yet, somehow I know it would work.

Comment: I get what you say about using int instead of short for IDs. The reason I chose short is because parent table's amount of rows will never exceed 15,000 for sure. Therefore, I don't need the full size of an integer number. However, since I realized RowId exists, I wonder: if the embedded Room's RowId works as an ID, why should I make my own ID?

Comment: i think it would be only in order to be able to reference it in your childTable as a foreign key

Comment: Hi, just a quick plead no to let that bounty go to waste ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. A clean way would be to wrap it in a function like this:

```
fun saveParent(parent: Parent): Int {
    val rowId = parentDao.insert(parent) // Returns Long rowId
    val parentId = parentDao.getIdForRowId(rowId) // SELECT id FROM table_parent WHERE rowid = :rowId
    return parentId
}
```

This function could be part of a repository class to make it even more clean.
Your functions in DAO can return the rowId and Parent.ID like this:

```
@Insert
fun insert(parent: Parent): Long

@Query("SELECT ID FROM table_parent WHERE rowid = :rowId")
fun getIdForRowId(rowId: Long): short
```

If you want to get basic functionality working first, you can call the Room database functions on the main thread when you build your database with `allowMainThreadQueries()`:

```
MyApp.database =  Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase::class.java, "MyDatabase").allowMainThreadQueries().build()
```

Like this, you can postpone background processing to later. If you have specific questions about that subject, it is better to ask a separate question.

Comment: Oh, Kotlin (so cute, but I still use Java :P). Anyway, I figure out looking at your answer that DAO's create methods are able to return an ID? Good to know... I have to try this out

Comment: Since you like 'clean', go Kotlin! You will never look back. :) See my edit to get the rowId from insert method.

Comment: I guess Kotlin is more concise no doubt... but this old dog (I mean me) is still afraid of not being able to adapt to Kotlin yet (same excuse to procastinate learning Kotlin for 2 years already)... anyway you have a point, Kotlin is less boilerplate code than Java, that's for sure...

Comment: Anyway, I will try to imitate the code you posted in your answer when I have more time. It looks like doing a SELECT to retrieve the auto-generated ID is inevitable (as I feared); however, returning it from the `saveParent` method directly from the repository seems **so clean**, I want to try it this way! :-)

Comment: Oh, oh! My repository performs the "insert parent" operation using an AsyncTask (which I have been warned is deprecated). One way or another, I cannot avoid having to do the INSERT in a different thread than the MainThread, right? So imitating your answer will take time... I might need several days just to test your answer in my code

Comment: I added extra information to the question that might be of your interest. Thanks for your time

Comment: The 'clean' way: take it step-by-step and post a new stackoverflow question for follow-up questions. :) Otherwise different questions and answers in this question (maybe also from others) will soon become very cluttered. Also title and content won't match any more.

Comment: I guess you might be right about that: for now I just add the related info here to keep track on how I am dealing with answers, feedback and stuff. So maybe I will have to open a third question (this one counts as second), **but my coding time is out! T_T**! I have to start preparing to go to work (and this time I don't work as programmer or anything related with computers), so I will have to go on later... maybe days later... T_T

Comment: Great! In due time, mention your next question here, I can have a look. Also, if you think this question is answered, you can upVote and accept the answer.

Comment: For now I don't have any more (first upvote to this answer is mine :wink:), however I shall keep an eye on this one and focus my efforts on the given answer for now. Also, "questions" like: `is it time to think of refactoring AsyncTask? Maybe...` is actually rhetorical... more to force myself to think about it than anything else...should I avoid this kind of rethorical questions, or instead exposing them as `maybe I should...` affirmations? I wonder...

Comment: IMHO, a more important question would be: shall I try Kotlin for my viewmodel, repository and dao classes? You can easily convert a class to Kotlin (right click on the class file), it will work normal with other Java classes. In Kotlin, you don't use AsyncTask but coroutines and suspend functions, which are so much cleaner and easier to use, especially since you are already using Room ...

Comment: Thanks for the advice about Kotlin (indeed, my Android Studio shown me today in the "Tip of the day" how to convert Java classes to Kotlin)... and I knew long ago that Java classes can work together with Kotlin classes... however, I'd rather use Java for now until I complete the basic functionality of my App (I will consider refactoring to Kotlin in the long term, not now)... even so, **aren't there coroutines and suspend functions in Java?**

Comment: Now that I watch your snippet closer, I see something weird in it: this line of code `val parentId = parentDao.getIdForRowId(rowId)`... **what's the point?** Isn't `parentDao.insert(parent)` already returning the new Parent's instance ID already?

Comment: Room insert does not return the parent id / primary key but the rowid, check here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data.

Comment: For basic functionality, you can consider using Room allowMainThreadQueries(), so there is no need for asyncTask or coroutines. You can then later decide how to get the database access functions of the main thread. And no, coroutines / suspend functions do not exist in Java. Instead Java has the 'callback hell' ;).

Comment: So, considering I am too stubborn to start using Kotlin yet, callbacks are the only way in case I don't want to execute queries in the main thread, right? (thanks for the feedback about `allowMainThreadQueries` BTW). Late or soon, due to `AsyncTask` is deprecated, I shall investigate if I can make it cleaner making my own `Thread`s, `Threadpools` and stuff like that (even though I'd appreciate if someone could enlighten me about this thing in his answer).

Comment: I updated the question with code that already works (see LONG STORY SHORT section). While typing this, I noticed you updated the answer. I shall keep updating and improving this question, and, if needed, I might end up opening a new question as well.

Comment: actually executing queries on the main thead  is bad practice and I dont even know if it is allowed in production. Instead of using threads you should use Executors and create a single thread executor. because issues may arise if more than one thread tries to access the DB at the same time. then there is the observable pattern for room which you should definitely use. Ill find you a link to a tutorial soon